# When using setTitle:forState: (UIButton) it produces strange results

Tags: objective-c, uibutton, interface-builder

I am doing en exercise from my programming book. I have set up a small custom view in Interface Builder.

[image: Custom view]

I have set "Edit"-button's event to `toggleEditMode:` in *File's owner*.

The view controller that is handling the view (the view is a table header view) has the following implementation of `toggleEditMode:`

```
- (IBAction)toggleEditingMode:(id)sender
{
    if (self.isEditing)
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"Edit"
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self setEditing:NO
                animated:YES];
    }
    else
    {
        [sender setTitle:@"Done"
                forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        [self setEditing:YES
                animated:YES];
    }
}
```

In Interface Builder I have also set File's owner custom class to my view controller. The `UIView` background is also set to the correct property in the view controller.

**The problem**

- When I press "Edit", its name changes to "…", which is not what it's supposed to do.
- However, it does behave properly if I change the name to "12345" in Interface Builder.
- If I change the name to "Edit2" (note, also five letters), it changes to "D…e".
- If I name it to something short, like "NS", it also produces three dots.

Does anyone know what's going on? I followed my book, and in the book it works properly.

Comment: Look at the frames of these buttons. This sounds like a truncation issue because the button is simply not wide enough to show "Done". You can easily see this if you change the backgroundColor of these buttons to something you can see. Adjust your autolayout constraints so the button is wider than it is currently. In your case the "Edit" button should start at the edge and go until the center of the view, and the "New" button should start there at the center and continue to the other edge.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch Yes, it turns out that the button wasn't wide enough. I increased its width, and now the problem doesn't occur anymore. If you make your comment an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: Full credit should go to Matthias Bauch, who answered this in the comments.*

The text strings that are too long for  a button will be truncated. To solve this you make the frame of the button larger, by draging in the corners of it (in Interface Builder).